# How do you make a font dialog in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help making a font dialog in tkinter.

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

def fontDialog():
    root2 = Toplevel(root)
    root2.geometry("300x300")
    root2.mainloop

button = Button(root, text="font dialog", command=fontDialog)

root.mainloop
```

So in def fontDialog, I made a screen. I don't know how to make a font dialog that changes the font family and size. If you do please help.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. _"Please build upon it"_ isn't a proper question. Plus, this question shows absolutely no signs that you did any research before asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A font chooser is very simple to make. All you really do is run a loop on `font.families()` and `insert` the return of each iteration into a `Listbox`. From there, you just tell it to change the `family` of a persistent font reference to whatever is selected in the `Listbox` when the `Listbox` is clicked. The font will change for anything that has the persistent font reference applied to its `font` option.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        #persistent font reference
        textfont = font.Font(family='arial', size='14')
        
        #something to type in ~ uses the persistent font reference
        tk.Text(self, font=textfont).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
        
        #make the textfield fill all available space
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        #font chooser
        fc = tk.Listbox(self)
        fc.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nswe')

        #insert all the fonts
        for f in font.families():
            fc.insert('end', f)

        #switch textfont family on release
        fc.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda e: textfont.config(family=fc.get(fc.curselection())))
        
        #scrollbar ~ you can actually just use the mousewheel to scroll
        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns')
        
        #connect the scrollbar and font chooser
        fc.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        vsb.configure(command=fc.yview)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.title('Font Chooser Example')
    app.geometry(f'800x600+200+200')
    app.mainloop()
```